# WinRT function Packagemanager class retrieves metro app details which are not convincing

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

So, I've been trying to retrieve details of metro apps installed in my system. I used the class [packagemanger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br240960?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and FindPackages() function in the class. 
Under the property Name, I am getting details as follows.
1. Microsoft.VCLibs.110.00
2. 48007TomaszChocyk.Ten
3. 9E2F88E3.Twitter
4. Microsoft.WindowsCalculator
These names are misguiding and are not very convincing.
Please guide me on whether there is any alternative way to get proper names of the metro apps installed in the system.
Also this function shows so many apps and all the apps are not directly available in the system. Some of them seems to be supporting backend apps. Is there any method to divide the physically accessible metro apps from all the other apps.?

Thanks